# ClickHouse error (version 21.6.6): Code: 1000 DB::Exception: Exception: Connections to all replicas failed

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

I am trying to connect ClickHouse with a local MYSQL database, ie, using the Engine MySQL.
I have run this commands to obtain the important data.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM amazon_redshift.analytics limit 10;

+-------+------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| count | date       | store_id | created_at | updated_at | ret_cust_rate               | orders_ret_cust               | recommendation_accuracy |
+-------+------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
|   875 | 2021-03-01 |   199703 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 | {"new":"1","returning":"0"} | {"new":"100","returning":"0"} | NULL                    |
|   425 | 2021-03-01 |   212743 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 | {"new":"1","returning":"0"} | {"new":"100","returning":"0"} | NULL                    |
|    81 | 2021-03-01 |   213745 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 | {"new":"1","returning":"0"} | {"new":"100","returning":"0"} | NULL                    |
|   189 | 2021-03-01 |   204112 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 | {"new":"1","returning":"0"} | {"new":"100","returning":"0"} | NULL                    |
|   309 | 2021-03-01 |   204125 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 | {"new":"1","returning":"0"} | {"new":"100","returning":"0"} | NULL                    |
|   761 | 2021-03-01 |   209940 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 | {"new":"1","returning":"0"} | {"new":"100","returning":"0"} | NULL                    |
|   699 | 2021-03-01 |   214119 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 | {"new":"1","returning":"0"} | {"new":"100","returning":"0"} | NULL                    |
|   913 | 2021-03-01 |   201062 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 | {"new":"1","returning":"0"} | {"new":"100","returning":"0"} | NULL                    |
|   792 | 2021-03-01 |   210493 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 | {"new":"1","returning":"0"} | {"new":"100","returning":"0"} | NULL                    |
|   182 | 2021-03-01 |   203925 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 | {"new":"1","returning":"0"} | {"new":"100","returning":"0"} | NULL                    |
+-------+------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
10 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

```
mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Connection id:      13
Current database:   amazon_redshift
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
UNIX socket:        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Binary data as:     Hexadecimal
Uptime:         2 hours 53 min 46 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 52  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 157  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 76  Queries per second avg: 0.004
--------------

mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', -1) AS ip,  @@hostname as hostname, @@port as port, DATABASE() as current_database;
+-----------+--------------------------------+------+------------------+
| ip        | hostname                       | port | current_database |
+-----------+--------------------------------+------+------------------+
| localhost | helena-ZenBook-UX451FL-UX289FL | 3306 | amazon_redshift  |
+-----------+--------------------------------+------+------------------+
```

```
$ sudo lsof -i TCP:3306 
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  1134 mysql   27u  IPv4  42528      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)
```

Then I run the docker Image of clickHouse:

```
CREATE DATABASE dummy ENGINE = Memory;

CREATE TABLE dummy.analytics
(
    `count` UInt8,
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `store_id` bigint NOT NULL,
    `created_at` date NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` date NOT NULL,
    `ret_cust_rate` text,
    `orders_ret_cust` text,
    `recommendation_accuracy` text
)
ENGINE = MySQL('localhost:3306', 'amazon_redshift', 'analytics', 'root', 'Password9876')


SELECT *
FROM dummy.analytics
LIMIT 10;
```

Received exception from server (version 21.6.6):
Code: 1000. DB::Exception: Received from clickhouse-server:9000. DB::Exception: Exception: Connections to all replicas failed: amazon_redshift@localhost:3306 as user root.

Does someone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is using *localhost:3306* where localhost points to the container, not the external host.

For testing purposes consider using [network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)-settings as *host* to have access to host network:

```sh
docker run --network="host" ..
```

---

As an alternate way can be used *docker-compose* to host both MySQL and ClickHouse (see for example [CH & Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534244/get-empty-rows-when-sending-log-from-kafka-to-clickhouse)).

Comment: So, I have to use an image to run mysql and a image to run clickHouse? I can't use my local mysql database and a docker image?

Comment: Command `docker run --network="host" -d --name some-clickhouse-server --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 yandex/clickhouse-server` works. However 
the command `docker run --network="host" -it --rm --link some-clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server` returns docker: links are only supported for user-defined networks.
I also tried without --network="host" and returns `docker: Error response from daemon: conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior.`

Answer (score 1):

Intead of using docker I started the clickHouse client in other way:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates dirmngr
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E0C56BD4
echo "deb https://repo.clickhouse.tech/deb/stable/ main/" | sudo tee \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/clickhouse.list
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y clickhouse-server clickhouse-client

sudo service clickhouse-server start

clickhouse-client --password=<your-password>
```

And then use another command:

```
CREATE DATABASE analytics ENGINE = MySQL('127.0.0.1:3306', 'amazon_redshift', 'root', 'Password9876')
```

And it work correctly like in the ClickHouse example (https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/database-engines/mysql/)

Answer (score -1):

your mysql need visitor ip white list